# Why there is a difference in the number of launch configurations received from the python script and AWS CLI?

Tags: python, boto, aws-cli

The python script that returns the list of launch configurations is as follows ( for the us-east-1 region):

```
autoscaling_connection = boto.ec2.autoscale.connect_to_region(region)
nlist = autoscaling_connection.get_all_launch_configurations()
```

For some reason the length of nlist is 50, i.e we found only 50 launch configurations.  The same query in AWS CLI results in 174 results:

```
aws autoscaling describe-launch-configurations --region us-east-1 | grep LaunchConfigurationName | wc
```

Why is so big deviation?

Comment: did you get your question answered? If yes please accept the answer to reward the user for taking the time to help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `get_all_launch_configurations` has a default limit of 50 returned records per call. It doesn't seem to be specifically documented for that `boto2`'s function, but a similar function `describe_launch_configurations` from `boto3` mentions that:

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/autoscaling.html#AutoScaling.Client.describe_launch_configurations

> **Parameters**
>
> ***MaxRecords*** (integer) -- The maximum number of items to return with this 
>   call. The default value is 50 and the maximum value is 100.
>
> ***NextToken*** (string) -- The token for the next set of items
>   to return. (You received this token from a previous call.)

The same parameters are supported by `boto2`'s  `get_all_launch_configurations()` under names `max_records` and `next_token`, see [here](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/autoscale.html?highlight=get_all_launch_configurations).

First make a call with `NextToken=""` and you'll get the first 50 (or up to 100) launch configs. In the returned data look for `NextToken` value and keep repeating the call until the returned data comes back without `NextToken`.

Something like this:

```
data = conn.get_all_launch_configurations()
process_lc(data['LaunchConfigurations'])
while 'NextToken' in data:
    data = conn.get_all_launch_configurations(next_token=data['NextToken'])
    process_lc(data['LaunchConfigurations'])
```

Hope that helps :)

BTW If you're writing a new script consider writing it in **boto3** as that's the current and recommended version.

**Update - boto2 vs boto3:**

Looks like **boto2** doesn't return `NextToken` in the return value list. Use **boto3**, it's better and more logical, really :)

Here is an actual script that works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import boto3

def process_lcs(launch_configs):
    for lc in launch_configs:
        print(lc['LaunchConfigurationARN'])

client = boto3.client('autoscaling')

response = client.describe_launch_configurations(MaxRecords=1)
process_lcs(response['LaunchConfigurations'])

while 'NextToken' in response:
    response = client.describe_launch_configurations(MaxRecords=1, NextToken=response['NextToken'])
    process_lcs(response['LaunchConfigurations'])
```

I intentionally set `MaxRecords=1` for testing, raise it to 50 or 100 in your actual script.

Comment: MLu Why "while 'NextToken' in data:" should bring us inside the loop? For me this does not work

Comment: @Alex - You're right, the *boto2* function doesn't return *NextToken* in the return value, not sure where the authors intend to get the value from. Use **boto3**, it's better, more consistent and more logical. Added a boto3-based working and tested script for your convenience. Hope that helps.